# Недопонимание с printf()

Tags: c, строки, вывод, printf, буферизация

ОПИСАНИЕ ПРОБЛЕМЫ НАХОДИТСЯ ВНИЗУ, А ТУТ НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНАЯ ВВОДНАЯ ЧАСТЬ

Есть две функции, первая из них получает строку с расположением файла, вторая получает все файлы по этому расположению (я не уверен, что проблема именно в этих функциях, но для наглядности все таки вставлю их)

```
char *fun_get_cur_path(void){
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof (char) * BUF_PATH);

    if( getcwd(buf, BUF_PATH) == NULL){
        if(errno == ERANGE){
            printf("Buffer is small\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        perror("Can't get current dir");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
   // printf("\n");
    return buf;
}

int list_in_dir(const char *path, struct dirent **new_entry)
{
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dir;
    int i = 0;

    dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open path: %s\n", path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ( (entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if( !strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        new_entry[i++] = entry;
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return i;
}
```

Ну и есть main

```
int main(){
    char *buf_path = NULL;
    struct dirent *entry[COUNT_OF_FILES];
    int count_of_entry_files = 0;

    buf_path = fun_get_cur_path();
    count_of_entry_files = list_in_dir(buf_path, entry);
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("FILES\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < count_of_entry_files; i++)
        printf("%s\n", entry[i]->d_name);
    printf("\n");

}
```

В чем собственно проблема: когда я запускаю данный код, то выводится следующее:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
FILES

-------
eg
test
main.o
Makefile
testing.txt

Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

А должно выводиться следующее

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
FILES

ASCII.jpeg
test
main.o
Makefile
testing.txt

Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

То бишь занки `-----` замещают название файла. Если я отключаю буферизацию для `stdout`, то все работает. Или если я добавляю `printf("\n")` в конец функции `fun_get_cur_path()`, то тоже вроде бы работает(но мне кажется это временно, пока я не увеличу количество символов `-----`).

В чем может заключаться проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читаем документацию на `readdir`

> The pointer returned by readdir() points to data which may be overwritten by another call to readdir() on the same directory stream.

Также

> Save the data from readdir(), if required, before calling closedir(), because closedir() frees the data.

Нельзя сохранять *указатели*, возвращенные `readdir`. Данные, на которые возвращенный указатель указывает, могу быть разрушены следующим вызовом `readdir`. А после `closedir` эти указатели протухают вообще.

Comment: разобрался, спасибо) впредь буду внимательнее относиться к документации, её же не просто так пишут